# How to use get prompt message of shell script by Java Process

Tags: java, shell

I am using java.lang.Process to execute shell script which requires user input interactively.
I can't get the prompt message of requesting user input in Java.

In this example, I want to get **"Enter your name: "** during the execution in Java Process.

```
read -p 'Enter your name: ' name;
echo "Hello, $name!"
```

I have tried to get shell script output by Process InputStream and ErrorStream.
They can only get the echo output.

This code only print

**outputFuture: Hello, myName!**

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "read -p 'Enter your name: ' name; echo \"Hello, $name!\"");
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStream es = process.getErrorStream();


// Create a separate thread to read the output of the process
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

Future<String> outputFuture = executor.submit(() -> {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        return line;
    }
    return null;
});

//Input myName to continue shell script  
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
os.write("myName\n".getBytes());
os.flush();
Thread.sleep(1000);

//Reading ErrorStream
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    LOGGER.info("error reader: {}", line);
}
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
LOGGER.info("Script exited with code " + exitCode);


// Display the output of the process
String output = outputFuture.get();
if (output != null) {
    LOGGER.info("outputFuture: {}", output);
}

executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: If you are going to do this (I *personally* suggest you don't), you will need to start multiple threads to handle the reading and writing from the external process. Executing a shell script from Java is possible, but it was not a major design goal for the language (and starting the JVM just to spawn a shell to prompt for user input has to be some kind of antipattern).

Comment: That's not your real use case. You're not going to get proper advice for your particular case unless you tell us what it is

Answer (score 1):

The `-p` argument to `read` is only honored when stdin is attached to a terminal. Quoting from the shell's source code:

```c
  /* If the -p, -e or -s flags were given, but input is not coming from the
     terminal, turn them off. */
  if ((prompt || edit || silent) && input_is_tty == 0)
    {
      prompt = (char *)NULL;
#if defined (READLINE)
      itext = (char *)NULL;
#endif
      edit = silent = 0;
    }
```

You *could* wrap the copy of bash in something like `unbuffer` to emulate a TTY (`ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/unbuffer", "/bin/bash", "-c",`...), but I'd generally suggest not relying on `-p` at all in the first place (there's a reason tools built to be programmatically invoked generally accept arguments via environment variables or the command line).